# Fastest way to add 50 million records to AWS ElasticSearch

Tags: java, database, elasticsearch, pentaho, aws-elasticsearch

I am trying to identify a way using which I could load data to elastic search.
AWS-ES provides bulk-api's but there is a limit set by aws on the payload size.

Can you please let me know what is the fastest way to fetch the data from DB2 and put it into AWS-ES. Record count is around 50 million and each record could have around 1 to 3 KB payload.

I have already tried using java module and Putting data to ES via API call but it is very slow.

Is there any **ETL tool** or **any service** available that could read JSON or csv and put data to ES?

Comment: Have you considered using Logstash? Are you sure that each row weights between 1 to 3mb? Isn't it too much? Even 1mb rows would turn into 50tb and that's a lot to deal with.

Comment: Updated the size. Thank you! Logstash - I have not tried.

Answer (score 4):

Hi you can use a simpe nodejs small app.
I tried many solutions (logstash included), but I found the most usable is to write a small code using nodejs.

I tested on local machine (low performance) using a JSON file of 10K records for a total of 35MB.

**Requirements: nodejs, npm**

1. Create a new working folder.
2. Go the created folder.
3. Type `npm install fs`
4. Type `npm install etl`
5. Type `npm install JSONStream`
6. Type `npm install elasticsearch`
7. Create a new `index.js` file and paste the following code with your data (elasticsearch server, json file). *In this case I put the json data file in same folder*.

Paste following code in index.js

```
var etl = require('etl');

var fs = require('fs');

var JSONStream = require('JSONStream');

var elasticsearch = require('elasticsearch');

//change with your data
var client = new elasticsearch.Client({
  host: 'localhost:9200', 
  log: 'trace'
});


var readStream = fs.createReadStream('file.json') //change with your filename

readStream    
  .pipe(JSONStream.parse('*'))    
  .pipe(etl.collect(100))    
  .pipe(etl.elastic.index(client,'testindex','testtype')) //testindex(your index)- testtype your es type
```

Run `node index.js`

**How it works?**

1. declare the modules required
2. create a ES client and connect
3. read the json file creating a stream
4. pipe the stream, parse each JSON object (my file contains 10K objects)
5. collect 100 objects using etl
6. index elasticsearch adding the 100 objects collected

Using ETL you can also import csv (and other formats)

More information and specs : [ETL](https://github.com/ZJONSSON/node-etl#readme), [JSONStream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/JSONStream), [Elasticsearch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/elasticsearch) (nodejs)

Comment: There is issue in ETL that you can't change the data type of property while indexing. By default it adds text for all fields.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Logstash to one time or continuously fetch data from a DB to Elasticsearch. Follow [instructions](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/installing-logstash.html) on how to install Logstash and then you just need a JDBC jar for your db and Logstash's config file. Template for the config file:

```
input {
  jdbc {
    jdbc_driver_library => "LOCATION_OF_db2jcc4.jar"
    jdbc_driver_class => "com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver"
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:db2://_DB_CONNECTION_DETAILS"
    jdbc_user => "user"
    jdbc_password => "pass"
    jdbc_paging_enabled => "true" #Useful for big data sets
    jdbc_fetch_size => "50000"
    jdbc_page_size => 100000
    #schedule => "* * * * *" #Uncomment if you want to run your query continuously 
    statement => "SELECT * from table" #Query that selects data which you want to download
  }
}
output{
    elasticsearch {
    index => "YOUR_INDEX_NAME-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
}
```

After you have created the config file start Logstash and it will start data import from DB. Importing big data sets might cause some problems so you should assign at least `5 GB` of ram to Logstash even more would be better. If some problems occur then you should tweak `jdbc_fetch_size` and `jdbc_page_size` parameters.

If you want to download data from a DB continuously and for example only latest data then read about `sql_last_value` parameter.

**Edit:**
You can also output indexes to AWS ES using Amazon Elasticsearch Output plugin so you don't have to configure the endpoint, you can read how to install the plugin [here](https://github.com/awslabs/logstash-output-amazon_es). Output configuration with the plugin:

```
output {
    amazon_es {
        hosts => ["foo.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com"]
        region => "us-east-1"
        aws_access_key_id => 'ACCESS_KEY'
        aws_secret_access_key => 'SECRET_KEY'
        index => "YOUR_INDEX_NAME-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
        }
}
```

A video explaining how to integrate Logstash using this plugin:
https://www.oreilly.com/learning/how_do_i_integrate_logstash_with_amazons_elasticsearch_service_es

Comment: Will this work with AWS ES? AWS-ES has insert limits of 10MB, 100MB depending on cluster size.

Comment: It should work without any problems, I have updated the answer with additional option for an output. I haven't heard about any inserts limit, can you provide source?

Comment: Hey Michael, I tried whatever you have mentioned but when I try to run the command, it gives me error.                                                                             C:\logstash-6.4.0\bin>logstash.bat -e C:\logstash-6.4.0\config\POC.conf
Starting Logstash {"logstash.version"=>"6.4.0"}
[2018-09-10T17:16:21,405][ERROR][logstash.agent           ] Failed to execute action {:action=>LogStash::PipelineAction::Create/pipeline_id:main, :exception=>"LogStash::ConfigurationError", :message=>"Expected one of #, input, filter, output at line 3, column 1 (byte 76) after "

Comment: Looks like your configuration file is incorrect.You should make a new question for this error.